# GlideApp not working After Migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, appglidemodule

GlideApp not working after migrate to the AndroidX. 
i tried to use Kapt as the `annotationProccessor`, change the GlideApp 4.8.0 to 4.9.0

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.0'
implementation 'com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.dv-ha:floatingsearchview:v1.0.4'
implementation 'com.lapism:searchview:4.0'
implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Facing Error : error: cannot find symbol class GlideApp

Comment: Could you update what type of  error you are getting?

Comment: show your logcat and code

Comment: `implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }`

Comment: error: cannot find symbol class GlideApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add following lines in your app level build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha3'
annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha3'
```